# Override types for built-in methods on prototype

Tags: javascript, typescript

The default type for `hasOwnProperty` is `hasOwnProperty(v: PropertyKey): boolean;`. However, this prevents me from doing things like:

```
const obj = { a: 1 };

function foo(str: string) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(str)) {
        console.log(obj[str]);
        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: number; }'.
    }
}
```

To override the type for `obj.hasOwnProperty`, I added:

```
interface Object {
  hasOwnProperty<T extends ObjectOf<any>>(this: T, key: any): key is keyof T;
}
```

This works for `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)`, but not `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)`. How can I override `hasOwnProperty`'s type when I call it using the second method?

Edit: to clarify, even with the override, the following doesn't work:

```
const obj = { a: 1 };

function foo(str: string) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, str)) {
        console.log(obj[str]);
        // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: number; }'.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a lite bit more what you want to achieve? or why you want to override hasOwnProperty? For me, this `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key) ` works like `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` and I achieve same result.

Comment: `obj.hasOwnProperty` is using my overridden type, but `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` is still using the default type

Comment: @LeoJiang I have to admit, you are asking interesting questions :D

Answer (score 2):

**FULL UPDATE**

I was wrong, I have overriden only `call` method.

*I'm sorry for providing you with bad example.*

With my previous code, calling `Object.prototype.[any prototype method].call` would act like typeguard which is wrong.

Previous **wrong** code:

```js
interface CallableFunction extends Function {

  call<T, Prop extends string, R>(this: (this: T, property: Prop) => R, thisArg: T, property: Prop): thisArg is T & Record<Prop, string>;
}
```

Above code means that `Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call` will act as a typeguard because I have typed only `call`.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```js
type Tag = { [prop: `tag${number}`]: never }

interface Object {
  hasOwnProperty(v: PropertyKey): boolean & Tag
}

interface CallableFunction extends Function {
  call<
    T,
    Prop extends string,
    R extends boolean & Tag
  >(this: (this: T, property: Prop) => R, thisArg: T, property: Prop): thisArg is T & Record<Prop, string>;
}

declare const obj: { name?: string, surname?: number }

if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'name')) {
  const test = obj.name // string
}

if (Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(obj, 'name')) {
  const test = obj.name // string | undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBUCGBzWBeWBvWBtSAnAe0gC5YADUFAEkwDsBXAWwCNp8BfcgXTLugBu7WBxABLOqHYAzRAGM4AeRYAraHNBZgsWAAtEAZ0UB3OgAUiMfBAAUAsheLsIAaWjgAlGRaFCAG2hEOlgAMgQUYFFgCSl8WQVYAGFEPz9EFgCAMQY6DTFCYOgADyk6ABMDWGzc0HzgzG1YORS-AB5GnXgAGg7YR0hYYtKK2ANQfAlkHp0dACVBkuhyyp9-QOCwpGRGgD4bUF0xAzJ9w%20OELtgCJ2twB0sPdB3YWcuDo4BBfGQybqvLZx3PoPMjvAxfVBHBChF7qQj4MqtfqXMYTOjIHYAbkiIDK6jS%20DgcgKY1ghFUZGwdEQTGgAH4yKjJiiGPhqbSGbBGKxhFExNJYDZlGoNAA6a6gQgQGCi-RGUz9QGi5qpGzklSXADk7Ogmo8jwaOmJdFJUlJGHVop1sAA9DbRuNJjjogKhap1KBxURJdLoF6bhAAJIGACi3PY6QCypaatUWp1eoNjWNpug5rJqitNLgdodaNQAB9YDk8dIJNAys6gA)

How does it work ?

I have created a brand type `Tag` and intersected it with `hasOwnProperty` return type.

What it gives to me?

`call` method is able to infer return type of `hasOwnProperty`. This is the only way to know which prototype method was called.

Then, I added constraint to `R` generic type. `R` is an infered return type from prototype method. In our case it is `boolean & Tag`. This is how `call` method is able to figure out that we have called `hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that its hard to understand your motivation for doing this, here is my best guess at what you're trying to achieve:

```
interface Object {
    hasOwnProperty<T extends ObjectOf<any>>(this: T, key: any): key is keyof T;
}

interface ObjectConstructor {
    readonly prototype: Object;
}

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}

if ((Object as ObjectConstructor).prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

Without casting:

```
interface Object {
    hasOwnProperty<T extends ObjectOf<any>>(this: T, key: any): key is keyof T;
    readonly prototype: this;
}

if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}

if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: I added clarifications, this isn't really overriding Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, it's just casting to a different type

Comment: @LeoJiang Thanks for the clarifications. Honestly, this was just a guess given that I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing. I don't get an implicit 'any' type like you're seeing and therefore can't play around and verify a solution. I used casting to follow the default TS object definition conventions. Adding version without casting.

Comment: @LeoJiang After finally absorbing what you're trying to accomplish and exploring possible solutions, I'm throwing in the towel. Without understanding TS internals better, it seems like this won't be possible. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5101) that started the whole discussion over there. Basically, since `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` cannot infer the return type of `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` to be a type guard (predicate), you are left with a boolean return and therefore no type narrowing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried, a little bit dirty, but you get what you want whit this workaround.

```
const example = {
     eProperty:'hello',
     e2:1,
     e3:[123,432,'paco']
} 
foo(str: string) { 
   if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(example, str)){
   let index = 0;
   for(let k in example){
     if(k === str){
       break;
     }else{
       index++;
     }    
   }
 // a is a array that index 0 is the key and index 1 is the value
    let a = Object.entries(example)[index];
    console.log(a[1]);
}
// logs hello
foo('eProperty');
```