# Typescript index signature failure Angular objects

Tags: typescript, indexing, types, signature

I have the following angular typescript code.

In the function 'blendBinA' keep getting the error:

> "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any'
> can't be used to index type 'ObjA'.ts(7053)"

How to fix ?

```
interface ObjA {
    propA: string;
    propB: number;
    propC: string[];
}

public objA: ObjA = { propA: 'Henk', propB: 23, propC: ['singel 23'] };
public objB: any = { propX: '6445 GB', propA: 'henk' };

blendBinA() {
    for (const k in this.objB) {
        if (this.objA.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            this.objA[k] = this.objB[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `this.objA.hasOwnProperty(k)` does not acts like a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

You need to define your own custom typeguard:

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
```

and then try:

```js
interface ObjA {
  propA: string;
  propB: number;
  propC: string[];
}


const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

class Foo {

  public objA: ObjA = { propA: 'Henk', propB: 23, propC: ['singel 23'] };
  public objB: any = { propX: '6445 GB', propA: 'henk' };

  blendBinA() {
    for (const k in this.objB) {
      if (hasProperty(this.objA, k)) {
        this.objA[k] = this.objB[k];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWBBZBvAWAChlkAHKAezOwC5kBnMKUAcwG5jSLqAhekAFcAtumicS5KmQDC9JixCsA2gF0JAX2LaiCSiCbIAFnAYAFadDABPZAF5kAHgyYANMgvVkEAB6QQACYMjMxsAHwAFJRY9C7uPGT0nmQAlFzI9NGYyMDBLsgAZMgAShB6UAGOye6CIADWIJQA7iBh9mHpLmVgAHQ8YJQ2ZBA9JgyoLclW1j0IcAA281FY8dIpEsQI86bBAGKUlPg63ILo88AIyFl0aFi4DnhS1DcA5AASEPUvq3z0AEwAZh%20snoyheDDYEHmyEBL1UyA0EhOZwuVyw-GQcBAtgeTzIAA16C8AGwAFlJAFZkABxXjfPGvIyfOovBEbSRnT4BXigbARFJHSSkGCUKDICJ6AxgZB1HIgZBgIy5HpZXgCwhC0g5GDisZTKA2CKK5XXdx1FLq9JarXGhgqu7KOrwhy2%202YXiO9RWrVaTW%200i%20jRAA)

If it possible, try to type `objB`

P.S. It is possible to force `hasOwnProperty` to behave like typeguard:

See this example:

```js
type Tag = { [prop: `tag${number}`]: never }

interface Object {
  hasOwnProperty(v: PropertyKey): boolean & Tag
}

interface CallableFunction extends Function {
  call<
    T,
    Prop extends string,
    R extends boolean & Tag
  >(this: (this: T, property: Prop) => R, thisArg: T, property: Prop): thisArg is T & Record<Prop, string>;
}

declare const obj: { name?: string, surname?: number }

if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'name')) {
  const test = obj.name // string
}

if (Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(obj, 'name')) {
  const test = obj.name // string | undefined
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68001036/override-types-for-built-in-methods-on-prototype/68136715#68136715) you can find related question and answer with more explanation.

[Here](https://catchts.com/FP-style) you will find my article with some examples