# Mapping object with correct type narrowing in mapper function

Tags: typescript, object, mapping

I'm porting a project to typescript and everything went fine except for this simple utility function:

```js
function mapObject(obj, mapperFn) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => mapperFn(key, value))
  );
}
```

It is used for transforming keys and values of an object, like so:

```js
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let mappedObj = mapObject(obj, (key, value) => [
  key.toUpperCase(),
  value + 1,
]);

mappedObj; // { A: 2, B: 3 }
```

**edit** *For the sake of clarity, the output object's entry values aren't necessarily identical to the ones in input object, e.g. the above example could've transformed the numbers into a string to result in `{ A: '2', B: '3' }`, or just return null for each of them: `{ A: null, B: null }`. Also, I only consider string keys in both input and output objects for simplicity and because that's how it is used in our project.*

I'd like `mapperFn` to retain the object entries' value types, *supporting type narrowing by key*, just the same as `GetEntryOf` does in the example below:

```
type GetEntryOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T];

interface TestI {
  str: string;
  num: number;
}

let entry: GetEntryOf<TestI>;

if (entry[0] === 'str') {
  entry[1]; // string
} else if (entry[0] === 'num') {
  entry[1]; // number
} else {
  entry; // never
}
```

This is the closest I've got, unfortunately I needed to transition to using `key in obj` operator:

```
function mapObject<K>(
  obj: K,
  mapperFn: (key: keyof K, value: K[typeof key]) => [string, unknown]
): Record<string, unknown> {
  const newObj = {} as Record<string, unknown>;

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
      const value = obj[key];
      const [newKey, newValue] = mapperFn(key, value);

      newObj[newKey] = newValue;
    }
  }

  return newObj;
}

interface TestI {
  str: string;
  num: number;
}

let test: TestI;

mapObject(test, (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'str') {
    return [key, value]; // value should be string
  } else if (key === 'num') {
    return [key, value]; // value should be number
  } else {
    return [key, value]; // value should be never
  }
});
```

As you can see, `value`'s type does not get narrowed correctly:

[image: mapObject type narrowing issue]

Considering that `GetEntryOf` can do it, I'd think that it should be possible to do the same inside `mapperFn`. Is this even possible in current typescript, and if so, what is the appropriate way to do it?

*Notes: The working type narrowing example is based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141960/typescript-key-value-relation-preserving-object-entries-type/60142095#60142095). I'm aware of and okay with the constraint mentioned in the same answer: "it is not guaranteed that the value does not also have other properties".*

Comment: COuld you please provide several examples of the output you expect

Comment: So the fundamental issue is that `value` is of type `string | number` (in your example) regardless of your narrowing `key`? I suspect you can't solve that with `mapObject`'s current signature. If you could define it to accept a tuple instead of two discrete parameters I suspect you could though. But that would involve changing the existing code to accept tuples rather than discrete parameters.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Exactly, I want `value` type to be narrowed from `string | number` in the if branches, in the else branch resulting in type `never`. As a relatively novice typescripter I'm not sure I understand what it means to "accept tuples rather than discrete params", but if I get it right you're saying that it can not be done without changing fn signature and thus how it is invoked.

I'd be okay with changing the signature to `(entry)` from `(key, value)` or any other thing that doesn't alter the way the whole function is invoked too much.

Can you provide an example to tuple invocation?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I messed up the ping. See above for answer / question. :)

Comment: (A [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) is basically a fixed-length array where the elements have their own types. `[number, number]` is a tuple.) I'm saying I'm not *sure* it can be done without switching to tuples. :-) Sadly, I'm not having much luck doing it with tuples, either, but I have this feeling it's possible. @captain-yossarian is much more knowledgeable on TS than I am, hopefully he can help.

Comment: @Abel consider this example https://tsplay.dev/NrvJ3N . In order to narrow the type, you are not allowed to destructure your object. Using `key` and `value` arguments is basically means using (...params:[key:string, value:number|string])=>...
It mans that instead of two arguments you should use a union type of one data structure. It might be a `tuple`, just like @T.J.Crowder said or it might be an object. Does not matter

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Just for what it's worth, TypeScript doesn't like the callback at the end of that playground (and I can't immediately understand how to fix it -- I tried [making it throw in the `never` case](https://tsplay.dev/N9J8Vm), but no luck).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I forgot to add `readonly`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type MakeTuple<T> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: { key: Prop, value: T[Prop] }
}>

type Output<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: [Prop, T[Prop]]
}


const mapObject = <K,>(
  obj: K,
  mapperFn: (params: MakeTuple<K>) => [MakeTuple<K>['key'], MakeTuple<K>['value']]
) => (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof K>)
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    const [newKey, newValue] = mapperFn({ key, value: obj[key] });

    return {
      ...acc,
      [newKey]: newValue
    }

  }, {} as Output<K>)


interface TestI {
  str: string;
  num: number;
}


declare let test: TestI;


const result = mapObject(test, (obj) => {
  // const key = params[0]
  // const value = params[1]
  if (obj.key === 'str') {
    return [obj.key, obj.value]
  } else if (obj.key === 'num') {
    return [obj.key, obj.value];
  } else {
    throw new Error();
  }
});

result.num // ['num', number]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqA%20KBeKTAbQGsIQB7AM0IF0Aoe0SKAWTjMyTAQi1wLxkadAG96UKEQAKAJwpgoASwB2UMpRqZaALiij15PXIUAaKADdEKPcRNhaUAL70n2Rs2gB5JMDC-%20fH0JKXtlNQ1qOj0ZeTBzOzjaBhdGAGMKFVRgKABbODAvACMAKwg0nIJ0AGlTbAAKEIpSvVqQ-LBIWQAxFT16sDhZOFzUPXZObl4a7ABKfFwiCYguHj5q7CIAcg0t2nNl1emN7athPYZ5vFx64rKKgDoNVHrmkvm4VCgAQVlhkHQkRoG1mIQesggABMkGkIPV6nA0mlzBorrhxJJJBksjkiCoIAB3arkcz4glCFCOAgdLq9eoGDTmM42KBvUjkRxOWYAbkYmKgEOASFkagx-KgD0liORIX5eMJxJAuigZIpEFlzj5znMoicUE%20UB8fgCIMY9FUwAgsioiOgmDQwAAksFJNlZHo3aoAOa8yQqJC5PT%203JFK281L0SHlBBDaC8HKW7K2B2O3npTLZAVoJAISp5Ap3crAeqJ4DmV6lNEuqAAehrUGxmY0QUGw1GRAADAxJHWGxmcszoARWyNUEQAIzd5Q0CslJ7kfB4AhbN1beZiySC4VqIhvecgcx7wdTvUQBCoaBKGd75tL5fBtfVzcQIUiqQ3kms0oPY%20%205xQM8LyfKBgAAC3kAkVUJKAAFE-goWR6h5EIXC5NMIVQHNgAeYNa3rbYH1JANQ1kWggA)

I'm not sure why you are using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)` but you can use :

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
```

instead.
You can even overload `hasOwnProperty` like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68001036/override-types-for-built-in-methods-on-prototype/68136715#68136715)

**UPDATE**
You will be allowed to use two separate arguments in

```js
const result = mapObject(test, (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'str') {
    return [key, obj]
  } else if (key === 'num') {
    return [key, obj];
  } else {
    throw new Error();
  }
});
```

when this PR [Control flow analysis for destructured discriminated unions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46266) will be merged

Comment: Nice! But **ugh** on the `reduce`. Simple loops for the win. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know that simple loops are faster. Just like `reduce` more :D Nest time will use simple loop )))

Comment: it's not about speed, it's about legibility and unnecessary, error-prone complexity.¹ But if you like it... :-)  *(¹ Outside of functional programming with predefined, reusable reducers.)*

Comment: I have noticed that many people dont like `reduce`

Comment: Three comments before I answer my question: 1) I hate hasOwnProperty, it was only needed due to the use of the `in` operator, which was my best bet to solve this issue before asking you guys 2) I should've made it clear that the output's type is not relevant, or, better put: the value type can't be known as it is possible to return any value from the mapper fn 3) I agree that `reduce` shouldn't be used to avoid obfuscation and reduce mental load on reader. That said, I could very quickly get to the perfect solution, I've already refactored most of the project and it's working wonders. 1000x <3

Answer (score 0):

Based on [captain-yossarian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813006/6035231) here is the end result that will be implemented:

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type MakeTuple<T> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: { key: Prop; value: T[Prop] };
}>;

interface MapObjectMapper<K> {
  (params: MakeTuple<K>): [string, unknown];
}

export default function mapObject<K>(
  obj: K,
  mapperFn: MapObjectMapper<K>
): Record<string, unknown> {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof K>).map((key) =>
      mapperFn({ key, value: obj[key] })
    )
  );
}
```

I've extracted the mapper function signature for the sake of legibility and replaced output type with `[string, unknown]` to account for the edit note in the question (using only string keys) and the fact that the return value indeed can not be known.