# Trigger warning when `this` context is lost through callback usage

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

In Javascript `this` gets lost when an object's method is passed as a callback parameter like this: `run(obj.myfunc)`. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74369963/how-to-access-the-correct-this-when-using-a-method-as-callback/74369964?noredirect=1#comment131293721_74369964))

I'd like to get a warning or error in case this is happening in the source code.

1. How can I trigger a compiler warning ( `tsc` ?) or linter warning ( `eslint` ) if the `this` reference for the object gets *lost*?
2. extra: Is there a way to trigger the warning only if loosing `this` actually has an impact on execution? I.e. if the object in question does not have member variables or does not make use of this, no warning will be issued.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I believe it should be done on `eslint` level, however there is something you can do to make your code a little bit safer.

Consider this example:

```js
const foo = {
    name: 'foo',
    fn(this) { // this is required if you want to make it type safe
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}



const callback = <Cb extends (this: { name: string }) => void>(cb: Cb) => {
    cb(); // expected error
    cb.call({ name: 'hello', fn: () => { } }) // ok
}

const arrowFn = () => { }

callback(arrowFn)
callback(foo.fn)// error because of contravariance
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKOn8W)

As you might have noticed, I have provided `fn` method with explicit `this` context notation. It means that context is important for this method (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thisparametertypetype)).

Than, function `callback` expects a callback which is context sensitive. TS forbids you to call `cb` without context. You are allowed to call `cb` only with `Function.prototype.call`, see `cb.call({ name: 'hello', fn: () => { } })`

However, it is still very tricky. TS allows you to use `arrowFn` as an argument, because this function does not expect any arguments, just like `cb`.
See this:

```js
declare let withContext: (this: { name: string }) => void
declare let nonContext: () => void

withContext = nonContext // ok
nonContext = withContext // ok
```

**So, why we have an error here ?:**

```js
callback(foo.fn) // error
```

Consider this example:

```js
type ThisA = { name: string }
type ThisB = { name: string, fn: () => void }

// #FIRST EXAMPLE
declare let a: ThisA
declare let b: ThisB
a = b // ok
b = a // error

// #SECOND EXAMPLE
declare let thisA: (this: ThisA) => void
declare let thisB: (this: ThisB) => void

thisA = thisB // error
thisB = thisA // ok
```

In #first example, `b` is assignable to `a`, and it is expected. However, is #second example, `thisB` is no more assignable to `thisA`, bit `thisA` is assignable to `thisB`. It is called `contravariance`. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) about it.

Let's summarize. If you want to pass a callback which is `this` dependent, you need to explicitly type this dependency:

```js
const foo = {
    name: 'foo',
    fn() {
        console.log(this)
    }
}

const callback = <
    Cb extends (this: { name: string, fn: () => void }) => void
>(cb: Cb) => {
    cb(); // expected error
    cb.call({ name: 'hello', fn: () => { } }) // ok
}
```

TypeScript has some interesting typings of `this` in s, my [article](https://catchts.com/FP-style#fp_utils) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68001036/override-types-for-built-in-methods-on-prototype/68136715#68136715)

**EXAMPLE WITH CALSSES**

```js
interface Base {
    name: string
}

class Bar {
    say(this: Base) {
        return this.name
    }
}

class Foo {
    constructor(public name: string) { }

    log(this: Base) {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}



const callback = <Cb extends (this: Base) => void>(cb: Cb) => {
    cb(); // expected error
    cb.call({ name: 'hello' }) // ok
}

const foo = new Foo('Ternopil')
const bar = new Bar()
bar.say() // not safe, because `bar` don't have own `name` proeprty

// ok, because we expect a callback which requires only `name` property, see Base interface
callback(foo.log)
callback(bar.say) // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2zV4w)

Assume we don't care what class it is. What we care is that class method should expect `this` to have a `name` property. I have created a `Base` interface with `name` property and explicitly defined `this` type on `say` method and `log` method

Please be aware that it is not safe, because `bar` instance does not have own `name` property

Comment: I'm not really following. Could you provide an example based on classes?

Comment: @DarkTrick made an update